# How To Read A Remote Text File

Tags: html, objective-c, text, ios4

I would like to read a remote text file called posts.txt on my website. An example of the insides of the posts.txt file would be this:

```
<div style="width : 300px; position : relative"><font face="helvetica, geneva, sans serif" size="6"><b>2</b></font><font face="helvetica, geneva, sans serif" size="4"><i> scored by iSDK</i></font><br><img src="Bar.png" /></div><div style="width : 300px; position : relative"><font face="helvetica, geneva, sans serif" size="6"><b>2</b></font><font face="helvetica, geneva, sans serif" size="4"><i> scored by martin</i></font><br><img src="Bar.png" /></div>
```

What I wanted to know is how can I get the score, and scored by text from the .txt file? The score is (in this case) the: `<b>2</b>`, and the scored by text in this case would be: "scored by iSDK". Any code telling me how to do this is twice as helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about how to get the remote file or how to extricate your data from the file? Your question seems to point at the latter, the title at the former.

I'm assuming hereafter that your question covers the parsing of the file.

Your code will go something like this (typed in browser; usual caveats apply):

```
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"fileFromServer"];
int scoreIndex = [file indexOfString:@"<b>"];
// use this to find your score (the number starting at (scoreIndex+3) )
int attrIndex = [file indexOfString:@"<i>"];
// use this to find the attribution string
    // (the sequence of non-"<" characters starting at (attrIndex+3) )
```

That should get you on the right track.

Comment: I was asking how to extricate my data from the file. I am getting the warnings 'stringWithContentsOfFile' deprecated and NSString may not respond to 'indexOfString'.

Comment: I'm on a Windows PC at work right now, so I don't remember the exact method names.

Comment: could the indexOfString be substringFromIndex?

Comment: if the issue is how to parse the html to get to the text part, why not actually use a text file? format: score tab name of person scored by newline next record

Comment: or use a php script on your page getscore.php?by=iSDK that simply returns the "2" you are looking for and nothing else.